# Add start and end word fields for tracked changes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add two word fields at the start and end of each track change of a document.

I am iterating through the word revisions using a for-each loop.

Below is my code :

```
Private Function TrackChangesOnDeletions(ByRef WordRange As Word.Range)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim fTrackRevisions As Boolean
Dim objRevision As Word.Revision
Dim objContentControl As Word.ContentControl
Dim objRange As Word.Range
Dim objField As Word.Field
Dim index As Long

Dim objRangeCopy As Word.Range
Dim objFieldEnd As Word.Field

With WordRange.Document
    fTrackRevisions = .TrackRevisions
    .TrackRevisions = False
End With

With WordRange
   For Each objRevision In .Revisions
       On Error Resume Next
       With objRevision
           Set objRange = .Range

           'Make sure there's no break character that may exist at the end of the specified range,
           'in order to avoid end field appears at the beginning of the next line.
           If Len(.Range.Text) > 0 Then
               Select Case Asc(WordRange.Characters.Last)
                   Case 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
                       .Range.MoveEnd Unit:=WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
               End Select
           End If

           'Create a copy of the passed range.
           Set objRangeCopy = .Range.Duplicate
           With objRangeCopy
               .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
               'Ensure we are not at an end-of-row marker.
               Do While .Information(wdAtEndOfRowMarker) = True
                   .MoveEnd Unit:=WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=1
                   .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
               Loop
           End With

           'Create a new field at the specified range.
           Set objFieldEnd = objRangeCopy.Fields.Add(Range:=objRangeCopy, Type:=wdFieldComments, PreserveFormatting:=False)
           'Insert end tag
           objFieldEnd.Code.InsertAfter " >"

           Set objRangeCopy = .Range.Duplicate
           objRangeCopy.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
           objFieldEnd.Update

           'Insert the start tag
           Set objField = objRangeCopy.Fields.Add(Range:=objRangeCopy, Type:=wdFieldComments, Text:="Deletion< ", PreserveFormatting:=False)
                objField.Update

           objRange.SetRange Start:=objField.Code.Start - 1, End:=objFieldEnd.Code.End + 3
           objRange.Font.StrikeThrough = True
           objRange.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed

           .Reject
       End With
       Err.Clear

       Set objContentControl = Nothing
    Next objRevision
End With

ErrorHandler:
    WordRange.Document.TrackRevisions = fTrackRevisions
    Set objContentControl = Nothing
    Set objField = Nothing
    Set objRange = Nothing
    Set objRevision = Nothing
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 0
        Case Else
            ShowUnexpectedError ErrorSource:="TrackChangesOnDeletions" & vbCr & Err.Source
    End Select

End Function
```

My issue is, once the code executed for the first revision, it gets the first revision as the next revision (at for loops' next) as well, event the revision count remain same. So the start and end fields keep adding to the first revision and it makes word crash.

For the below original text, 
[image]

I need the output as, 
[image]
When the field codes are hidden, it should display as :
[image]

But my code gives the output as, (I have manually stop the for loop iteration to have this capture, else it will add fields and fields and cause word crash) 
[image]
Form my further testings, I have identified that, if some text were inserted before the revision within the loop, the next revision will be same as the current revision. So the loop is running nonstop and then crash word.

Could anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've basically already asked this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266183/process-word-comments-inserted-within-inserted-deleted-text and not responded to a comment asking for clarification. What you're trying to do with a `Comments` field makes no sense. This field links to a single, specific *Document Property*. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @CindyMeister, Yes, in my case, it was something developed beforehand by some other one, and now I have to alter it to map with the new requirements. 
I have to process the track changes into those word fields (modifying the docx) . And there's another team who handle the docx to cxml conversion part. 
They have already implemented their converter by tracking the word field of type comment.  That's why I had no choice but had to use it.

Comment: And I thought to ask in a different question, as my main issue is different in here. 
Also now it is not necessary to use the word field with type comment, as I am going to build a new way to process the track changes to identify in the docx to cxml converter. 
I just need to pass the track changes without affecting the text to the converter in a way, so they can identify it correctly

Comment: What is `WordRange` - I mean, what does it represent? The entire document body? Because of `Set objRangeCopy = .Range.Duplicate` that happens in the loop. If this is the entire document body, then essentially the code is always restarting from the beginning of the document instead of continuing from each Revision?

Comment: Yes, `WordRange` is the entire document body. But in `set objRangeCopy = .Range.Duplicate`, I am duplicating the range of the revision (`set objRangeCopy = objRevision.Range.Duplicate`)

Comment: I have checked on other field types, other than the comment. Neither of them matched my task. When use field type comment, when field codes are hidden, it displays the converted track changes nicely to in the document (so that customer can easily identify the converted track changes). I'll upload the image when field codes are hidden in the question body.

Comment: OK... Since you don't really use `WordRange` for much of anything I'd remove that `With...End With` block in order to make things clearer. Then, use `objRange.Duplicate` instead of `.Range.Duplicate` in that With block. If that doesn't change anything, set a break-point in the loop, use F8 to step through the code and do a `Select` on the various ranges in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) so that you can *see* where they are each step of the way. (I'm on a mobile device and can't do any testing, currently.)

Comment: I have removed the `With...End With` block for `WordRange` and also used `objRange.Duplicate` instead of `.Range.Duplicate`, but the output made no change. I'll check with the immediate window.

Comment: I checked with the immediate window,  when I select the `objRevision.range`, every time it select the same range. Seems when content is added at the start of the revision, as the range changed, VBA is identifying the same revision as the next revision, even the revision count is not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to move out from the loop at correct time, I used the below approach. 
Any improvements or other answers are appreciated.

```
 Private Function TrackChangesOnDeletions(ByRef WordRange As Word.Range)

 On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim fTrackRevisions As Boolean
    Dim objRevision As Word.Revision
    Dim objRange As Word.Range
    Dim objRangeCopy As Word.Range      
    Dim objFieldStart As Word.Field
    Dim objFieldEnd As Word.Field
    Dim index As Long
    Dim revisionCount As Long

    With WordRange.Document
        fTrackRevisions = .TrackRevisions
        .TrackRevisions = False
    End With

    revisionCount = WordRange.Revisions.Count
    index = 1

    If (revisionCount > 0) Then
        Set objRevision = WordRange.Revisions(index)

        Do While Not objRevision Is Nothing
            If AllowTrackChangesForDeletion(objRevision) = True Then
                On Error Resume Next
                With objRevision
                    Set objRange = .Range

                    'Make sure there's no break character that may exist at the end of the specified range,
                    'in order to avoid end field appears at the beginning of the next line.
                    If Len(objRange.Text) > 0 Then
                        Select Case Asc(objRange.Characters.Last)
                            Case 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
                                objRange.MoveEnd Unit:=WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
                        End Select
                    End If

                    'Create a copy of the passed range.
                    Set objRangeCopy = objRange.Duplicate
                    With objRangeCopy
                        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                        'Ensure we are not at an end-of-row marker.
                        Do While .Information(wdAtEndOfRowMarker) = True
                            .MoveEnd Unit:=WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=1
                            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                        Loop
                    End With

                    'Create a new field at the specified range.
                    Set objFieldEnd = objRangeCopy.Fields.Add(Range:=objRangeCopy, Type:=wdFieldComments, PreserveFormatting:=False)
                    'Insert end tag
                    objFieldEnd.Code.InsertAfter " >"

                    Set objRangeCopy = objRange.Duplicate
                    objRangeCopy.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
                    objFieldEnd.Update

                    'Insert the start tag
                    Set objFieldStart = objRangeCopy.Fields.Add(Range:=objRangeCopy, Type:=wdFieldComments, Text:="Deletion< ", PreserveFormatting:=False)
                    objFieldStart.Update

                    objRange.SetRange Start:=objFieldStart.Code.Start - 1, End:=objFieldEnd.Code.End + 3
                    objRange.Font.StrikeThrough = True
                    objRange.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed

                    .Reject
                End With
                Err.Clear

            End If

            'Move to the next revision (unable to use for loop, because it iterates through the first revision everytime and
            'then crash word
            index = index + 1
            If index > revisionCount Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set objRevision = WordRange.Revisions(index)
        Loop
    End If


    ErrorHandler:
        WordRange.Document.TrackRevisions = fTrackRevisions
        Set objFieldEnd = Nothing
        Set objFieldStart = Nothing
        Set objRange = Nothing
        Set objRangeCopy = Nothing
        Set objRevision = Nothing
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 0
            Case Else
                ShowUnexpectedError ErrorSource:="TrackChangesOnDeletions" & vbCr & Err.Source
        End Select

    End Function
```